# why my start_request function is not calling my parse function in my scrapy program?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am trying the scrape the review of this particular IMDB title. But for some reason the start_request is not calling the parse function for this title alone. for another title, it seems to work.

Code examples:

```
class imdb(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imdb'
    
    def start_requests(self):
            c=("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8217188/reviews")
           
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=c,
                wait_time=4,
                screenshot=True,
                callback=self.parse)
             
            

    def parse(self, response):
        print("done")
```

Comment: It's work fine. any error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didnt bother to read docs

https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium

Anyways, try this code

```
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class MyBotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mybot'

    custom_settings = {

        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_TYPE': 'executable',
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME': 'chrome',
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH': r'c:\chromedriver.exe',
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS':[],
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
        },
    }

    def start_requests(self):
       
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8217188/reviews",
            wait_time=4,
            screenshot=True,
            callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Here")
```